# UIGestureRecognizer equivalent for hitTest: withEvent:

Tags: iphone

I have two views: view A (huge scroll view (map) with scrolling, zooming, etc.) and its subview B (with same size as A, subclass of uiview, only for drawing of routes). Before that I used hitTest: withEvent: function to forward all user events to A. But now, I have to recognize tap event on view B. I added UITapGestureRecognizer to B, but it didn't work, because all events were "hitten" to A. I comment this function, but now nor scrolling, nor zooming don't work, only tapping..Any ideas? Thank you very much!